# System.FormatException

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

No entiendo por qué me da ese problema, se donde es pero entiendo qué está mal, no se que puede se incluso escribí numero en todas las casillas para asegurarme que no este llamando a otra que no contenga un numero. El número que escribo es 0 o 1 para cerciorarme de que es un entero, por favor ayúdenme, estoy empezando es este mundo con C# y la idea es no usar ninguna estructura de datos ya saben como vectores y todo eso, aquí es donde me da error:

```
int gol1 = 0, gol2 = 0, gol3 = 0, gol4 = 0, gol5 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    nombre1 = dgvIngreso.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    eq1 = dgvIngreso.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString();
                    gol1 = int.Parse(dgvIngreso.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToString()); //Aquí es donde me da error
                    asis1 = int.Parse(dgvIngreso.Rows[i].Cells[3].ToString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, me dí cuenta que no había llamado lo que contenía esa celda por ejemplo:
yo escribí esto:

```
gol1 = int.Parse(dgvIngreso.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToString());
```

en lugar de esto:

```
gol1 = int.Parse(dgvIngreso.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()); ///Omitía el .Value
´´´
```